# JQuery - .click triggering when clicked anywhere should: upon clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63617776/Capture.PNG

So as on the image, when you click on the map, a div is changed. Now when I click on a link in the div, I want the google maps div to change to another map.

But, the code I wrote either doesn't trigger at all or it triggers when I click anywhere on the page.

```
$('#nowydwor').ready(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
         alert('foo');
    });
});
```

Ofcourse the link looks like this:
    {a id="nowydwor"} text {/a} (for some reason i couldn't enter < so I replaced it with {)

This triggers when user clicks anywhere on the page, for some reason. Also this is only a testcode for now, it is meant to display the alert. :) Any ideas?

EDIT: The link is contained in .html(), in a switch() statement.

```
case '#mazowieckie':
   $('#info').html("CONTENT </h5><hr><strong><a id='nowydwor'>Skład Nowy Dwór Mazowiecki</a></strong> CONTENT");
```

break;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `ready` only makes sense if you call it on the `document`/`window` to get notified as soon as the DOM is ready.

Try to bind the `click` handler on your DOM element directly:

```
$('#nowydwor').on('click', function(){
  alert('foo');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't trigger anything. I used the ready thingy because the link is in a $('#link').html('content link'); function, and it doesn't get interpretted until you click on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you were trying to do, is assign the click handler after the content of `#info` has changed. Unfortunately `.ready()` is only an event handler for the document ready event. It only fires once. Also changing the html of `'#info'` isn't triggering any events (IMHO).

You can work around this, using the `.on`-method on a parent element. Consider this html structure:

```
<div id="info">
  <!-- This content is dynamically loaded -->
  <a id="nowydwor">Click this to change map</a>
  <!-- End of dynamic content -->
</div>
```

This makes it possible to call:

```
$('#info').on('click', '#nowydwor', function(){ /* Change map here... */ })
```

This assigns the event handler to `#info`, which is only called if the clicked element matches `'#nowydwor'`. Since `'#info'` is never removed, only the content changes, you don't have to apply it again.

The only point is, you have to determine what the id of the map/place is, because the event handler will be the same for all links.